# Vue.js circular computed properties

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties, datadesign

I have an applicated that requires the update of two fields that depend on each other for their values.

For example:

```
<template>
    <tr>
        <td>{{total}}</td>
        <td><input type="text" v-model="calculateEarnedPercentage" @change="updatedForecastPercentage"></td>
        <td><input type="text" v-model="spent_dollar"></td>
    </tr>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                total: 1000000,
                spent_percentage: '',
                spent_dollar: 20000,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            updatedForecastPercentage () {
                this.vendor.regional_forecast_dollar = this.vendor.purchases / (this.vendor.regional_forecast_dollar / 100)
            }
        },
        computed: {
            calculateEarnedPercentage () {
                return (this.vendor.regional_forecast_dollar / this.vendor.purchases) * 100
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The two "spent" values depend on a static "total" value.  I will be storing the spent_dollar, and the percentage will be initially derived from that.

Now if the user updates percentage, I need the dollar value to update.
If they update the dollar value, I need the percentage to update.

As of now it obviously doesn't work.  Circular updates are happening.
How do you design your data to allow this functionality in Vue.js?

Comment: One is a real data item, the other is a writable computed.

Comment: If you are doing `v-model="computed property"`, then consider defining a `setter` for this computed property (`set` prop). Inside this setter you can apply some logic to your variables depending on the changed resulting value. Read about it: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

Comment: @wostex thank you!  I was not aware of the get/set dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you could use some watches and a mutex.
Taking an idea from parallel processing I built a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zx29m710/1/) to showcase this idea

```html
<div id="app">
  <span>{{ total }}</span>
  <span><input type="text" v-model.number.lazy="spent_percentage"></span>
  <span><input type="text" v-model.number.lazy="spent_dollar"></span>
  
  <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
</div>
```

```js
 new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data () {
        return {
          total: 1000000,
          spent_percentage: 5.0,
          spent_dollar: 20000,
          mutex: false,
          vendor: {
            purchases: 2358,
            regional_forecast_dollar: 1
          }
        }
      },
      watch: {
        spent_percentage: function(value, old_value) {
          if (!this.mutex) {
            this.mutex = true
            
            this.spent_dollar = (this.vendor.purchases * value) / 100;
            this.spent_percentage = value;
        
            this.mutex = false
          }
        },
        spent_dollar: function(value, old_value) {
          if (!this.mutex) {
            this.mutex = true
            
            this.spent_dollar = value;
            this.spent_percentage = (value / this.vendor.purchases) * 100;
            
            this.mutex = false
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: The mutex doesn't really do anything here since there is only one thread and there are no async operations inside each watcher. So once a watcher starts running it will finish executing its code before the other watcher will start, even without the watcher. Side effects (i.e. other watchers) are collected into a list and being executed after this code finishes.